# Format a dictionary and add line break

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I have such a dictionary below in python and i would love to format it by adding a line break to the last item.How can i edit my code to add a line break after the last item John?

d={'date': '07-Oct-2019', 'day': 'Monday', 'driver': 'John '}

print("\n".join([k+":"+v for k,v in d.items()]))

Note am getting such an output from within a loop

```
count = 0
for user in all_users.each():
        reeds = user.val()
        value = str("\n".join([k+" : "+v for k,v in reeds.items()]))
        if count <= 0:
            mylist.insert(END,  value)
            count + 1
        else:
            print("Error")
```

Comment: `d={'date': '07-Oct-2019', 'day': 'Monday', 'driver': 'John \n'}`, it should work

Comment: @harshit verma I have edited my question, i am getting that value from within a loop, so am not able to do that directly, i used that as an example.

Comment: I have added a answer

Comment: `value = value + "\n"` ?

Comment: What do you mean by `last item`? Does it depend on what the key is, or is it just whichever one happens to come last when you ask for the `reeds.items()`?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the k value is driver or not.

So replace `value = str("\n".join([k+" : "+v for k,v in reeds.items()]))` 
by this:

```
if k == 'driver':
    value = str("\n".join([k+" : "+v+"\n" for k,v in reeds.items()]))
else:
    value = str("\n".join([k+" : "+v for k,v in reeds.items()]))
```